# override the default "Details" text for <details> tag

Tags: css, replace, overriding

How can I override the default summary for the `<details>` tag without specifying a `<summary>` element in HTML?

It does not seem that the text "Details" is associated with `::before` or any other DOM object.

#### Example

```
<details id="preamble">
  <details id="content">
    <details class="outline-2">
      <h2>Heading 1</h2>
      <div>... content ...</div>
      <details class="outline-3">
        <h3>Heading 2</h3>
        <div>... content ...</div>
        <details class="outline-4">
          <h4>Heading 3</h4>
          <div>... content ...</div>
        </details>
      </details>
    </details>
  </details>
</details>
```

It looks like I may be able to achieve the above with [Org export's `HTML_CONTAINER` option](https://orgmode.org/manual/HTML-specific-export-settings.html), but it does not look like I can change the container for the headings.

So the goal is eventually to figure out a clever way to make the headings appear as the `<details>` summary without changing the HTML.  But for now, I am just trying to see if I can change the `<details>` summary to anything else.

Comment: If you don't specify a summary, what do you expect/want to be there to encourage the user to see that makes them want to interact with the details element?

Comment: Firefox DevTools shows it is in 'shadow DOM' using `<slot>`. I don't understand specifically, but I think it is some `<template>` given this [MDN example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_components/Using_templates_and_slots#creating_a_new_element-details_element_from_the_template) on page [MDN: Using templates and slots](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_components/Using_templates_and_slots).

Comment: I'm trying to work out a hack to get the first element of `<details>` to show as the summary. But to do that I would first need to control the shadow summary element. Maybe I can set a negative margin on it or use some other trick. Or maybe there's no way.

Comment: Time to post a [reprex] of what you are doing...